# Rails: No route matches error - due to constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, constraints

I'm getting the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /websites
No route matches {:controller=>"searches", :action=>"domain_results"}
```

when trying to use the following link helper:

```
<%= link_to website.domain, domain_results_path(website.domain) %>
```

I have domain_results defined in my searches controller and the following route set up:

```
get 'search/:domain/domain' => 'searches#domain_results', as: :domain_results, constraints: { domain: /.*/ }
```

rake routes:

```
domain_results GET    /search/:domain/domain(.:format)    searches#domain_results {:domain=>/.*/}
```

If I use the following it works:

```
<%= link_to website.domain, "/search/#{website.domain}/domain" %>

get 'search/:project/project' => 'searches#project_results', as: :project_results
<%= link_to website.domain, project_results_path(rental.project) %>
```

Is this due to the constraint I'm using? I had to use the constraints as I'm passing strings such as "google.com.au" into the path.

Comment: is it possible one of the website.domains you're using doesn't meet the constraint?

Comment: I've tried checking the route even with something like `domain_results_path("google.com")` which should work, but it showed the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
domain_results_path(:domain => website.domain)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was overseas. I tried `domain_results_path(domain: website.domain)` and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Paste the output from "rake routes"

Comment: I've added the output to my question.